# Show that an integral doesn't exist by using the limit of a Riemann sum

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, definite-integrals, riemann-integration

Given that
$$\ f(x)=\begin{cases} 0, & \text{if $x$ is rational} \\ 1, & \text{if $x$ is irrational}\end{cases}$$

I want to show that the integral
$$\int_0^1 f(x)\,dx$$
does not exist by using a Riemann sum and showing that it does not converge to a number.

I'm guessing that the Riemann sum that I'm searching for should look like this:
$$a_n = \sum_{i=1}^n \left(f\left(\frac{i-c}{n}\right)*\frac{1}{n}\right),\ c\in [0,1]$$

and that I'm supposed to show that
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n$$ does not exist.

Edit: I knew that the Dirichlet function is not continuous on [0,1] and that therefore it is not integrable when I made this post. This is the reasoning that I've seen for answers to similar questions.

I was wondering if it was possible to demonstrate that it is not integrable by coming up with a Riemann sum that does not converge.

Additionally, in the form that I suggested above, the variable c does not have to be rational.

Comment: You're using a right uniform sum formula here, which is fine for computing integrals of functions we **already know** are Riemann integrable, but can't always tell us if the function is not Riemann integrable. In this case, $f((i - c)/n) = 0$, because $(i - c)/n$ is always rational, which makes $a_n = 0$ for all $n$, hence the limit is $0$. But, this function turns out not to be Riemann integrable.